# Unshuffling a shuffled string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Learning about randomness and shuffling in python is really interesting. However, I have shuffled a string by using the following code:

```
string = "Shuffling in Python"
q = ''.join([str(w) for w in random.sample(string, len(string))])
```

Now, I have shuffled string so how can I  unshuffle it to get the original string back?

Comment: `string` is the unshuffled version. If you could reverse randomness it would not be  very random

Comment: Unrelated, but I would advise against using `string` as a variable name, as it's also the name of a module in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't do this without some trace of the original string. So, if you head the original indices (which you can get with `enumerate`), then you might be able to undo (still not a reverse) the shuffling:

```
In [18]: s = "Shuffling in Python"

In [19]: shuffled = random.sample(list(enumerate(s)), len(s))

In [20]: ''.join([e[1] for e in shuffled])
Out[20]: 'igf nfSonhult iPhyn'

In [21]: ''.join(s[e[0]] for e in shuffled)
Out[21]: 'igf nfSonhult iPhyn'

In [22]: ''.join([e[1] for e in sorted(shuffled, key=lambda x:x[0])])
Out[22]: 'Shuffling in Python'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The original order is not preserved, proper random shuffling is not a reversible operation.

Just like any random collection of letters, finding other words with those specific letters would require you to search through all possible valid words, and you could find multiple solutions.

Not that you *need* to unshuffle the letters. You still have the original string in `x`, you never removed that variable so you still have a reference to the original.